# How to run Command Prompt Commands in Yii2?

Tags: cmd, yii2

> Here i want to run my command prompt commands in yii2
>
> This is the command i want to run this yii2

```
C:\wamp\www\source>yii test\pending
```

> How can i use below button to execute the above command.

`<a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Execute</a>`

updated:

> TestController.php

```
public function actionPending()
{   

    $today = date('Y-m-d');

    $dt1 = ArrayHelper::map(Claimprocess2::find()->all(),'id','turn_around_time_set');
    $dt2 = ArrayHelper::map(Claimprocess2::find()->all(),'id','updated_at');
    $name = ArrayHelper::map(Claimprocess2::find()->all(),'id','id');
    foreach ($dt1 as $key => $value) 
    {
        $trt = print_r($value, true);
        $update = print_r($dt2[$key], true);
        $name1 = print_r($name[$key], true);

        if($today == $trt && $update == '')
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO pending (claimer_name, status, template, last_trt, email) 
                    SELECT claimprocess_start_for, status, template, turn_around_time_set, tpa_email  
                    FROM claimprocess_2 WHERE id=$name1";

            $query = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();

            echo "cron service runnning";
        }

    }

}`
```

> main-local.php

```
'consoleRunner' => [
        'class' => 'vova07\console\ConsoleRunner',
        'file' => '@console/controllers' // or an absolute path to console file
    ],
```

> pendingcontroller.php

```
public function actionTest()
{
    $return = Yii::$app->consoleRunner->run('test/pending');
    echo "$return";
}
```

> pending/index.php

```
<?= Html::a('Execute', ['pending/test'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

> getting value 1 while am pressing execute button, command is not executing
>
> Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try something like this :

Your HTML File.

```
<a href="test.php?runtest=true" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Execute</a>
```

test.php

```
<?php
if($_REQUEST['runtest']) {
  $result = shell_exec('yii test\pending');
  echo $result;
}
?>
```

But it can be very dangerous to execute shell command in php file.

Comment: Could you try it with simple command like `ls` or `dir` if you are on windows

Comment: @KalaiS, it works. Probably something wrong with path to yii executable.

Comment: @KalaiS one more way, which I'm using, You can move your code to component and use it in your console and web applications.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extension : [Console Runner](https://github.com/vova07/yii2-console-runner-extension)

Follow the above link and use this command to run the console job:

```
Yii::$app->consoleRunner->run('test\pending');
```

You can put the above code in controller action and call this action on click of the button.

**Updated:**

For eg.
**frontend\controllers\SiteController**

`use vova07\console\ConsoleRunner`;

```
public function actionIndex()
{

     $cr = new ConsoleRunner(['file' => '@my/path/to/yii']);
     $cr->run('test/pending');
}
```

**Consoler\Controller\TestController:**

```
public function actionPending()
{
    // Your code
}
```

Then you can call the index action as:

```
echo Html::a('Execute', ['site/index']);
```

Comment: i have installed this extension, where i can use this code $cr = new ConsoleRunner(['file' => '@my/path/to/yii']);
$cr->run('controller/action param1 param2 ...');

Comment: how i can give the link in button

Comment: You can call the action using the link. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: where i can use this code Yii::$app->consoleRunner->run('test\pending');

Comment: Bro keep on loading not at all executing

Comment: pls see above , i have updated question, and given a detail of what all i did

Answer (score 0):

Try this (If you want to execute via PHP):

> It's yii (without ext, not yii.bat)
>
> Make sure that php folder added to PATH variable (Windows)

```
$op = shell_exec ( 'absolute/path/to/yii ' . 'cache/flush-all' );
\yii\helpers\VarDumper::dump($op, 10, 1);
```

Output:

```
The following cache components were processed:

* cache (yii\\caching\\FileCache)
```

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the issue by adding these two extensions in php.ini file

```
extension=pdo.dll
extension=pdo_mysql.dll
```